# I got problem a about to call func from class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I got this code from a book name 'Data Structures and Algorithms in Python from Michael T. Goodrich ' chapter 5.5.1 Storing High Scores for a Game.

Can some one can explain to me what this `self._board[-1].get_score( )` means ??

I try to print it to see what happens but I got:

```
print(self._board[-1].get_score( ))

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_score'
```

```
class GameEntry:
 def __init__(self, name, score):
    self._name = name
    self._score = score
 def get_name(self):
  return self._name
 def get_score(self):
  return self._score
 def __str__(self):
  return ('({0}, {1})'.format(self._name, self._score)) # e.g., (Bob, 98)

class Scoreboard():
 def __init__(self, capacity=10):

  self._board = [None]*capacity # reserve space for future scores
  self._n=0 # number of actual entries

 def __getitem__(self, k):

  return self._board[k]

 def add(self, entry):

  score = entry.get_score()
  print(score)

  if self._n < len(self._board) or score > self._board[-1].get_score(): # what is it " self._board[-1].get_score()"
    if self._n < len(self._board): # no score drops from list
      self._n += 1 # so overall number increases

    j = self._n - 1
    while j > 0 and self._board[j-1].get_score( ) < score:
     self._board[j] = self._board[j-1] # shift entry from j-1 to j
     j -= 1 # and decrement j
    self._board[j] = entry
 def __str__(self):

  return '\n' .join(str(self._board[j]) for j in range(self._n))

a_ = Scoreboard()
a = ('a','b','c','d')
b = (5,4,8,4)
c = dict(zip(a,b))
print(c)
for i,j in c.items():
 x = GameEntry(i,j)
 print(x)
 y=a_.add(x)
 print(y)
```

Comment: The line: `self._board[-1].get_score( )` means "from the last item in `self_board` call the `get_score()` method" (because the code presumes it is a `GameEntry` instance)

Comment: How can i know the code presumes it is a GameEntry instance ? @quamrana

Comment: Ok, it doesn't have to be a `GameEntry` instance, just some object which has a `get_score()` method (and the only objects you have shown us are instances of `GameEntry` which you supply to the `add()` method).

Answer (score 0):

Inside your class `Scoreboard` you keep a list of game entries:

```
self._board = [None]*capacity # reserve space for future scores
```

This list is used to keep `GameEntry` entries:

```
self._board[j] = entry
```

The logic in your application uses `._n` to track the number of entries added, but only up to total number of score slots available (`self._n < len(self._board)`).

If this is `False` (i.e. the number of entries added is the same as the capacity of the entry list when it was initialized), the other part of the `or` statement gets executed:

```
score > self._board[-1].get_score()
```

This looks at the *last* element in `self._board` - i.e. what is supposed to be the slot entry with the lowest score to see if this score deserves to be entered into the list instead of the previous one. Any negative list index starts from the end of the list instead of the wrong, so `-1` points to the last entry, `-2` the second to last entry, and so on.

If you get a `None` entry while running your code (and not just printing it out *before you've added ten entries*) is another question, and is probably what you need to debug further (but it doesn't seem to be the case from your code). If you attempt to print that entry before inserting all ten entries (i.e. filling up the entry list), there won't be an entry in last place, and the `None` placeholder will still be there.